# How can we read the second line of a file using batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to retrieve the second line of a file (install.cfg) which contains a few lines of text.
I tried with below code which is working fine in my local machine, but when executed on a windows machine, it throws 'þ@' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%G in ('findstr /n "^" install.cfg') do if ( %%G equ 2 SET VERSION=%%H )
```

Comment: You presumably stored the batch with a wrong encoding/BOM. Use plain asci/ansi not UTF8/Unicode. Also the parentheses in the if are wrong - remove them.

Comment: No way that code works with the parentheses like that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this code in an ASCII/ANSI/OEM (one byte per character) and **not** [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) ([UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) or [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), multiple bytes per character) encoded batch file:

```
for /F "usebackq skip=1 delims=" %%G in ("install.cfg") do set "VERSION=%%G" & goto HaveValue
:HaveValue
echo Version read from file: %VERSION%
```

The character encoding used by Windows command processor by default in command line environment is output on running in a CMD window the command `chcp` (**ch**ange **c**ode **p**age) without any parameter and depends on the region/country/locale which is set for the used user account. It is advisable (usually, but not always) to write a batch file using same [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) respectively [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) as used by default by Windows command processor in the environment which is used on running the batch file, especially on batch file containing characters with a code value greater U+007F (non-ASCII character).

**FOR** expects file `install.cfg` being encoded with one byte per character. `install.cfg` can be also UTF-8 encoded without or with [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) as long as version string consists of only ASCII characters. A UTF-16 encoded `install.cfg` cannot be processed directly with command **FOR** using this code in default command-line environment loaded on double clicking on a batch file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `set /?`